# RAILS AS LISTED ONLY IDS SAME AS CURRENT USER

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Good afternoon. I'm new to Rails and I'm using Google Translate to post here.
I have these 3 tables, and their relationships:

```
table: ata_publics
- ata_public_id
- provider_id
```

```
table: ride_requests
- ride_request_id
- hitchhiker_id
```

```
table: payments
payment_id
ride_request_id
```

The relationship is like this:
Model: payment

```
belongs_to :ride_request
```

Model: ride_request

```
belongs_to :ata_public
has_one :payment
belongs_to :hitchhiker, class_name: "User"
```

Model: ata_public

```
has_many :ride_request
has_one :payment
belongs_to :provider, class_name: "User"
```

my question is: I want to list all payments that have the same provider_id as the current user.

If I try to do something similar in Payments:
self.ride_request.ata_public.provider_id to get the id of the provider, gives error:
NoMethodError: undefined method `ride_request'

I don't know if it got confusing, but when I list all the payments, they all come, I want only the payments that are from the provider_id equal to the current user.

```
  def index
    @payments = Payment.all
    
    render json: Paginate.new(
      pagination_params[:page],
      pagination_params[:limit]
    ).call(@payments), status: 200
```

[![imagem_table]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIzx2.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
@payments = Payment.all
```

to

```
@payments = Payment
  .joins(ride_request: :payment)
  .where(payments: { provider_id: current_user.id })
```

should work.